# Use Automator as an Applescript learning tool?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I am trying to teach myself AppleScript.  Is Automator based on AppleScript?  It occurs to me that if there is a way to view the AppleScript "guts" of an Automator action, that would be a great learning tool.  But is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to learn AppleScript is indeed to learn by example. [MacScripter](http://macscripter.net/) is the best place to start, without any doubt. Checkout the tutorials section and follow threads. Most problems you come across are already answered at MacScripter.

Automator is not based on AppleScript, it uses [ScriptingBridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html) and mostly private API's.  ScriptingBridge is an alternative to AppleScript for Cocoa developers (Objective-C), the syntax differs however greatly from AppleScript.

In conclusion, Automator is certainly not the place to start learning AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the link below and look at the "AppleScript Tutorial for Beginners" series. It's how I learned. Also you have a folder full of applescripts if you want to see a variety of code. Find it here: /Library/Scripts/. Also, under the help menu of AppleScript Editor is the "Applescript language guide". Finally, you will have to learn the terminology of the scriptable applications, so in AppleScript Editor file menu choose "Open Dictionary..." and choose an application in the list to see its applescript terms.

http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=25631